# MYSQL select from product table using filter stored in seperate table

Tags: php, mysql, database, filter

I have a database that contains two important tables. One table consists of our entire product catalogue. The other is a list of filters that has been selected from a back end panel for searching. For some reason this is showing a blank screen on execution. I'm pretty sure i'm being stupid and missing something stupid.

MYSQL logs show

```
SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE product_list.PRODUCT_NAME IN ('\'product1\' OR \'product2\' //etcetc
```

does anyone have any ideas? My script below:

```
echo "<table class='inventorydata'><tr><td>SKU</td><td></td><td>Title</td><td>Quanitity</td></tr><tr><td colspan='4'></td></tr>";
//table header

$filterproducts = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_filter_selection ORDER BY filter ASC");
$filterproducts->execute();
$filterselect = $filterproducts->fetchAll();
//select all set filters from the table

$filteroptions = "'";
foreach($filterselect as $filterRow){
$filteroptions .= $filterRow['filter'] . "' OR '";
}
//set filters in to a string

$truesearch = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE product_list.PRODUCT_NAME IN (:filterchoice)");
$truesearch->bindParam(":filterchoice", $filteroptions, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$truesearch->execute();
//use filters set as parameters for searching through products

foreach($truesearch as $rows){
echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['SKU'] ."<td/><td>". $rows['PRODUCT_NAME'] ."</td><td>". $rows['QTY'] . "</td></tr>";
}
//display products

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Firstly, check your error log on your server, is there anything there? Secondly, if you set a breakpoint in your script and step through do you see any issues?

Comment: Could you expand on what you want your "truesearch" query to look like? Now it looks like you're building a string and adding `' OR '` between the values. You then try to look for that string in your PRODUCT_NAME column. You can't add SQL-statements like that when using prepared statements. It won't concatenate the statement, it will use it as a literal string.

Comment: Pseudo: select all products from the product list. Truesearch is to find all rows that match one or more of the filters put in via ":filterchoice". Once the rows have been selected it is then to output them into a row of a html table. Made an edit as i realise i used a silly var name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this for the moment by just looping each filter and opening a connection every loop. Not the prettiest but it'll do for the moment. Thank you for the help.